# My discord bot can't properly send multiple responses to a command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My Discord bot (Discord.js) isn't replying correctly to the command.
when it asks "How is your day", and a user responds, the output is only from the "good response". So like, when you say that you had a bad day it'll respond: "That's great to hear!".

here is the code for my discord bot:

```
module.exports= {
    name: 'hello',
    description: "Greet the Best Maid from Genshin!",
    execute(message, args){
        let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
        message.channel.send("Hi! I am Noelle, maid of the Knights of Favonius. It's a pleasure to meet you, how was your day?"). then(() => {
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then(message => {
                message = message.first()
                if (message.content == 'Good', 'Great', 'Ok', 'Fine') {
                    const replies = ["That's GREAT to hear!", "Ohhh, how exciting!", "I hope that your days will continue to be wonderful"]
                    message.replytext = Math.floor((Math.random()*replies.length) + 0);
                    message.channel.send(replies[message.replytext]);
                } else if (message.content == 'Bad', 'Tired', 'Depressing') {
                    const replies = ["That's really unfortunate", "Oh my, it will get better", "I hope that your days will become fantastic onwards", "Would you like some tea to get rid off some stress?"]
                    message.replytext = Math.floor((Math.random()*replies.length) + 0);
                    message.channel.send(replies[message.replytext]);
                } else {
                    message.channel.send("I don't seem to understand")
                }

            })
            .catch(collected => {
                message.channel.send("It seems like you don't want to talk about it. I am free anytime if you want to talk about it. ^-^");
            });
        })
    }

}
```

here below is the "main.js"

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '>'

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('How may I be of assistance?');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'hello'){
        client.commands.get('hello').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == ''){
        client.commands.get('').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == ''){
        client.commands.get('').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == ''){
        client.commands.get('').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == ''){
        client.commands.get('').execute(message, args);
    }
});

client.login(Token)
```

Comment: Stepping through the code provided it seems as if it should produce the desired output; are you sure it's an issue with the program and not something else? Have you made sure that the bot is on the correct version?

Comment: The bot worked perfectly fine before the addition of the bot replying to the user's response.

Comment: @MorganS42, I uploaded my "main.js" file

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in your **if** statement.

```
 if (message.content == 'Good', 'Great', 'Ok', 'Fine')
```

This will always return true, because the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) returns the value of the last operand which is the string 'fine'. Strings in Javascript are truthy so this will always return true.

For a quick fix you can use the **or** statement

```
if (message.content == 'Good' || message.content == 'Great' || message.content ==  'Ok' || message.content == 'Fine')
```

Or if you want a more extendable option you can store all your good responses in a set, and then check that the set contains the option.

```
const goodResponses = new Set{['Good', 'Great', 'Ok', 'Fine']};
if(goodResponses.has(message.content){
... }
```

You will also have to do the same thing for the bad responses.

Comment: I tried both of your fixes but they all went to "message.channel.send("I don't seem to understand")", and it only sends "I don't seem to understand".

Comment: You could try logging the message.content, and seeing if it is an exact match with the any of the options. So try adding console.log(message.content) and seeing what you get from that

Comment: The console.log would just be to help diagnose the problem, there should be some output in your terminal with what the value is in the message.content so we can figure out why the if statement is not returning

Comment: oh alright
PS C:\Users\Guest user\Desktop\Noelle Bot> node .
How may I be of assistance?
>good
that is what came up in the terminal

Comment: It would depend on what IDE you were using to develop the bot, for example vscode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: it seems like whenever the negative words ('Bad', 'Tired', 'Depressing') are being inputted as the positive words. Whenever I type ">bad", the terminal shows that it is being inputted/received as ('good', 'great', 'ok', 'fine').

Answer (score 0):

The `,` operator in js chains multiple expressions together and returns the value of the last one which in this case is the string 'Fine'. 'Fine' is truthy, so your first `if` is always true.

To see if the message is contained in a list of words, your can instead use `includes` with an array:

```js
if (['Good', 'Great', 'Ok', 'Fine'].includes(message.content)) {
}
```

The above solution is still case sensitive, so you could optionally compare the lowercased message instead:

```js
if (['good', 'great', 'ok', 'fine'].includes(message.content.toLowerCase())) {
}
```

But it will still only match if the message is "Good" with no other words or characters. You can also make it check each word in the message (removing any non-letter or whitespace characters) to see if any of them match:

```js
// separated into a function so its reusable
const matchesAny = (str, words) => {
  const cleanedStringParts = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w\s]/g, '').split(/\s+/g)
  return words.some(word => cleanedStringParts.includes(word))
}

const options = ['good', 'great', 'ok', 'fine']
console.log('Good', matchesAny('Good', options))
console.log('good', matchesAny('good', options))
console.log('Good!', matchesAny('Good!', options))
console.log('>>good', matchesAny('>>good', options))
console.log('im doing good!', matchesAny('im doing good!', options))

console.log('bad', matchesAny('bad', options))
console.log('>bad', matchesAny('>bad', options))
console.log('foo', matchesAny('foo', options))
```

It can be used as

```js
const matchesAny = (str, words) => {
  const cleanedStringParts = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w\s]/g, '').split(/\s+/g)
  return words.some(word => cleanedStringParts.includes(word))
}

module.exports = {
    name: 'hello',
    execute: (message, args) {
        const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
        message.channel.send("How was your day?").then(() => {
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then(async messages => {
                const response = messages.first()
                if (matchesAny(response.content, ['good', 'great'])) {
                    // reply
                } else if (matchesAny(response.content, ['bad', 'tired'])) {
                    // reply
                } else {
                    await message.channel.send("I don't seem to understand")
                }
            })
            .catch(async collected => {
                await message.channel.send("It seems like you don't want to talk about it");
            });
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your fix but it went to "message.channel.send("I don't seem to understand")", and it only sends "I don't seem to understand".

Comment: What message are you sending? If you send "good" instead of "Good" it wont match any of the options.

Comment: Both "Good" and "good" have the same result

Comment: @K.O.R.D. I tested the above fix in my own testing discord bot, and it worked perfectly as seen [here](https://cdn.glitch.com/756c9678-a64f-4a10-b4c0-61b0f091de2c%2Fstack_noelle_test.jpg?v=1628134028081). [Here](https://cdn.glitch.com/756c9678-a64f-4a10-b4c0-61b0f091de2c%2Fstack_noelle_code.jpg?v=1628134039001) is an image of the code I used, if you want to compare yours to it to see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Cannicide I compared your code with mine and it's the same but the bot replies with "I don't seem to understand". 
I uploaded the "main.js" file

Comment: I dont know what your message.content is, but it isnt "good" or "Good". Ive added a 3rd option that will also work if you send ">good" or a sentence that contains the word "good"

Comment: @Villa7_ How would I integrate that to my code?
do I edit the "if" statement and put it under that?

Comment: `if (matchesAny(message.content, ['good', 'great'])) { }`

Comment: @Villa7_, the result becomes the "It seems like you don't want to talk about it. I am free anytime if you want to talk about it. ^-^" state.

Comment: it seems like whenever the negative words ('Bad', 'Tired', 'Depressing') are being inputted as the positive words. Whenever I type ">bad", the terminal shows that it is being inputted/received as ('good', 'great', 'ok', 'fine').